# AngularJS - Updating component bindings in controller before displaying it in template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

A component **bindings** attributes are available for the **template** before the **controller**.

The **template** will display the given value of `x` and not 2, since the **template** is loaded before the `$onInit()` is called, and modifying the value of `x` directly in the **controller** outside `$onInit()` won't be possible since the bindings attributes are available only in the `$onInit()`

1. How can I update `x` before displaying it in the **template**?
2. Suppose I want to call a **service** to get some data based on the given value of `x`, say `y`, this have to be done inside the `$onInit()` to have the value of `x` available, therefore any obtained value of `y` won't be available for the **template** because the **template** is loaded before `y` is obtained. How to solve this?

Example:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.component('comp', {
    bindings : { x : '<'}, 
    controller : function(){
        this.y;
        $onInit = function(){
              this.x = 2;
              YService.getY(this.x).then(function(response){
                this.y = response.data;
              });
        };
    },
    template : '<h1>x: {{$ctrl.x}}, y: {{$ctrl.y}}</h1>'
});

app.service('YService', function () {
  var service = {
    getY : function(x) {
      return x*2;
    }
  };
  return service;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.6.2" data-semver="1.6.2" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app='myApp'>
    <comp x=4></comp>
  </body>

</html>
```

A running example on [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/KwIEKY2ioE4UoTbUtEsA?p=preview)

Comment: this code doesn't even do anything.  you aren't updating the binding in that `$onInit` function, it would likely throw `x is undefined` instead.

Comment: use ng-if/show to hide the value and toggle it on when it is ready

Comment: `x` is an input, so it makes no sense to change it inside the component.

Comment: @zeroflagL ok, what about part 2? how to get y?

Comment: What about it? I don't understand what you mean by _"y won't be available for the template"_.

Comment: your question still doesn't make sense.  you keep saying that things won't be available to your controller, which is not correct, and you keep referring to your variables and properties incorrectly.  you really should create a [mcve] of your *actual issue*.

Comment: @Claies I updated the code by adding an example

Comment: ok, but even in that new example, your `$onInit` is updating a **variable** `y`, not a **controller property** `$ctrl.y`.

Comment: @Claies Even when adding y as a controller property, it will be 'empty' when displayed in the template, because the onInit is called after and y won't be updated on the template

Comment: that doesn't make sense.  The **entire purpose** of angular bindings is that they are "live" and update as the properties update.  as soon as the property has a value, the template will be re-rendered.  Unless your concern is a brief flicker?

Comment: @Claies I added a working plnkr link, please check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139843/discussion-between-eddyg-and-claies).

Answer (score 0):

can you try load your template with if condition to your h1 tag as below?

ng-if="{{$ctrl.x}}"

From your other scenario you can user "y" on ng-if..

Answer (score 0):

To refer to the binding variable inside the controller, you need to refer to the function context and using **this** instead of just **'x'**, the client running this piece of code will throw error 'x is undefined'.

Also, fews of your statement are incorrect, by referring to the function context, you can access to component's bindings anywhere inside the controller function, not limit to component lifecycle functions as **$onInit, $onChanges, $doCheck, $postLink and $onDestroy**.

The understanding that template is loaded before and hence cannot see bindings or any controller, scope variables, or cannot see variables set inside AJAX call, is not true. To be simple, if it's the case, AngularJS will never work. To render the component, AngularJS load the template, yes, but then compile it with the component scope, and create the linking that we call two-way binding, so changes inside the component controller, will be reflected in the view.

I suggest you do some reading about AngularJS component here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component.

Comment: can you please check the example: http://plnkr.co/edit/KwIEKY2ioE4UoTbUtEsA?p=info

Comment: @EddyG there are *quite a few issues* with that plunker;  for example:  You can't use `this` because it doesn't always reference the controller.  Your `$onInit` function isn't even a property of the controller, so it will never execute.  Your `getY` function doesn't return a promise, so you can't use `.then()`.